# What are some properties of the leading eigenvalue of a product of inversions in mutually tangent spheres?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, arithmetic-groups

Let $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ be a collection of $n \geq 4$ pairwise tangent hyperspheres in $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ with disjoint interiors, and $\iota_i$ be the inversion in $S_i$. Viewing the conformal group of $\mathbb{S}^{n-2} = \mathbb{R}^{n-2} \cup \{\infty\}$ as an index-2 subgroup of $\mathrm{O}(n-1,1)$ yields a representation of the product $\iota_1\ldots\iota_n$ as an $n \times n$ real matrix whose characteristic polynomial has integer coefficients. Since $\iota_1\ldots\iota_n$ maps the closure of the exterior of $S_n$ into the exterior of $S_n$ (indeed, into the interior of $S_1$), this matrix has a unique eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ of modulus larger than $1$. (The positive algebraic integer $\lambda_n$ is independent of all the choices made above.)

I was wondering what is known about the numbers $\lambda_n$. For instance, how does this sequence grow? Is the degree of $\lambda_n$ precisely $n$ for $n$ even, and $n-1$ for $n$ odd? A positive answer to the latter question would imply that the $\lambda_n$ are Salem numbers for all $n \geq 4$.

Comment: This paper might be relevant: https://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/cox/cox.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reference. As McMullen points out, the $\lambda_n$ are certainly Salem numbers in his (broader) sense; I was wondering if one could at least rule out quadraticity of $\lambda_n$ for $n \geq 4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I computed the matrices for $n=3,...,10$ in Mathematica and found the factorizations of the characteristic polynomials:

$$-(1 + x) (1 - 18 x + x^2),$$
$$ 1 - 68 x - 122 x^2 - 68 x^3 + 
  x^4,$$ $$-(1 + x) (1 - 228 x - 314 x^2 - 228 x^3 + x^4),$$
$$1 - 710 x - 2033 x^2 - 2708 x^3 - 2033 x^4 - 710 x^5 + 
  x^6,$$ $$ -(1 + x) (1 - 2166 x - 4913 x^2 - 6324 x^3 - 4913 x^4 - 
    2166 x^5 + x^6),$$
$$1 - 6536 x - 23780 x^2 - 42680 x^3 - 50618 x^4 - 42680 x^5 - 
  23780 x^6 - 6536 x^7 + 
  x^8,$$ $$-(1 + x) (1 - 19656 x - 58724 x^2 - 96120 x^3 - 109754 x^4 - 
    96120 x^5 - 58724 x^6 - 19656 x^7 + x^8),$$
$$1 - 59018 x - 255443 x^2 - 547448 x^3 - 792878 x^4 - 884732 x^5 - 
  792878 x^6 - 547448 x^7 - 255443 x^8 - 59018 x^9 + x^{10}$$

This seems to obey the pattern you seek. I’ve also checked this pattern up to $n=50$.

The maximal eigenvalues are computed to be
$$\{17.9443, 69.7628, 229.373, 712.857, 2168.27, 6539.64, 19659., \
59022.3\}$$

**Addendum:** Here is how I did the computation. In the Lorentzian model of hyperbolic space in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1,1}$, the $n$ planes intersecting $S^{n-2} \subset \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ in $n$ tangent spheres will be orthogonal to vectors $e_i$ such that $\langle e_i, e_i\rangle =1$ in the  Lorentzian product (here the hyperboloids defining hyperbolic space will be $\{x | \langle x, x\rangle =-1\}$). The tangency between the spheres corresponds to $\langle e_i , e_j\rangle =-1, i\neq j$ (see [Section 1.3 of this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10711-017-0280-7)).

Reflection through $e_i^{\perp}$ is given by $R_i(x)= x- 2\langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$, and thus we see $R_i(e_i)=-e_i, R_i(e_j) = e_j+2e_i, j\neq i$. From these formulas  we can write down matrices and compute the products $R_1\cdots R_n$, which is how I derived these computations in Mathematica.

One might be able to guess/ prove an inductive formula for the polynomials which then could yield the possibility of applying an irreducibility criterion. I can already see formulae for some of the coefficients of the matrices which might allow one to guess a formula for the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Now I've checked up to $n=50$.

Comment: Wow, that's fascinating! Thanks!